# Do bridge load-sensors follow linearity?

Tags: load-cell, bridge

I have been using four half bridge load-sensors. After forming a bridge, the output of the bridge is fed into ADC(ADS1230). I'm using this [load-cell](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/FREE-SHIPPING-20pcs-lot-Experiments-body-scale-wholesale-human-scale-load-cell-sensor-resistance-strain-50kg/32271599811.html). From the output of the ADC, I want to convert it into KGs simply by 'Slope-method', assuming the output of ADC to be linear. I only have to be confirmed that the load-cell behaves linearly or not when the huge weight is subjected to it.[image]

Comment: The datasheet for your load cell should give you a linearity spec. I can't remember when I last saw one which was any worse than 100ths or 1000ths of 1% though, so I doubt you'll need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, load cells are generally very linear; you can expect weight to map linearly to resistance within the cell's operating envelope.

Answer (score 1):

the linearity is typically 0.2% over 0 to max rated load. Decide the ADC resolution based on ratio of full scale to short term stability. This means a 11 or 12 bit load sesnor. If you have a more resolution from the ADC replace the last few bits with 0. A high accuracy ADc when used with a low accuracy load sensor yields a low accuracy answer for load. And load sensors requiring 0.01% (13 bit) ADC are not made as one would hardly require it.